# Jquery: second modal does not active

Tags: jquery, html

I get some problem that I cannot solve:
1. first modal at #exampleModal is working fine.
2. second modal does not work when post data to save at food_action.php but data already save into database but #modal_confirm does not toggle.
I do not know why. I try to debug and console.log which lines are error.
Please help.

Best regards

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Topup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 mx-auto pt-2">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-info"> back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">            
            <div class="col-sm-4 my-5">
                <div class="border border-primary rounded" style="height: 335px">   
                    <div class="text-center pt-5"><img id="stu_img" src="" class="rounded" style="width: 50px" alt=""></div>
                    <h2 class="text-center">Information</h2>
                    <dl class="row">
                        <dt class="col-sm-6 text-right">ID: </dt>
                        <dd id="id" class="col-sm-6"></dd>
                        <dt class="col-sm-6 text-right">Name: </dt>
                        <dd id="name" class="col-sm-6"></dd>
                        <dt class="col-sm-6 text-right">Level: </dt>
                        <dd id="level" class="col-sm-6"></dd>
                        <dt class="col-sm-6 text-right">Balance: </dt>
                        <dd id="balance" class="col-sm-6"></dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 my-5">
                <div class="border border-success rounded" style="height: 335px">
                    <h2 class="text-center pt-5">Topup</h2>
                    <form class="p-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Topup</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" name="card_amount" autofocus required>
                            </div>
                            <small class="form-text text-muted">Number only</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Register</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="register" name="who_check" value="admin" readonly>
                        </div>
                        <button id="btn_submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Top up confirm</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-10 mx-auto">
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>ID</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stu_id" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Amount</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stu_topup" readonly>
                                        </div>                      
                                        <button id="btn_confirm" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
                                        <button id="btn_cancle" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">cancle</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal_confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Topup complete</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-10 mx-auto">
                                    <p id="topup"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <script src="assets/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var stu_id = sessionStorage.getItem("id");
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.post("food_action.php",
            {
                list: "list",
                id: stu_id
            },
            function(data, status){
                //console.log(data[0].card_id);
                document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = data[0].card_id;
                document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data[0].stu_name;
                document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = data[0].stu_level;
                document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = data[0].card_pocket + " บาท.";
                $("#stu_img").attr('src', 'assets/img/'+data[0].stu_img);
            }); 
        });

        $('#btn_submit').click(function(){
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
            $('#stu_id').val(stu_id);
            $('#stu_topup').val($('#amount').val());
        });

        $('#btn_confirm').click(function(){
            console.log("press");
            $.post("food_action.php",
            {
                update: "update",
                add: "add",
                id: stu_id,
                action: "topup",
                register: $('#register').val(),
                amount: $('#amount').val()
            },
            function(status){
                //console.log(xhr.status);
                if(status = 'success'){
                    console.log(status);
                    $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#modal_confirm').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if(status = 'success')` don't you mean   `if(status == 'success')` ?

`=` means **equals**. `==` means **equal to**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `status =` part to use `==`.

```
        function(status){
            //console.log(xhr.status);
            if(status == 'success'){
                console.log(status);
                $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
                $('#modal_confirm').modal('show');
            }
        });
```

When you say `status = 'success'` then you're setting the value of `status` to 'success'. But you want to check if something is `equal to`, you don't want set values so for that we use `==` and not `=`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I changed it but it still did not work when I clicked button (#btn_confirm) in first modal only data was posted to save but #exampleModal modal will not hide and show another modal.